# Phaser sprite.kill() sometimes doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, phaser-framework

I'm writing some games with phaser and I'm facing a problem with the method sprite.kill().

**Sometimes when I call sprite.kill() Phaser seems to destroy the body for collisions/overlapping but the visual element(image and draggable object) still on screen.**

I've set the overlapping method for all my objects through a foreach:

```
garbList.forEach(function(g) {                                                                                                    
    trashList.forEach(function(t) {                                                                                               
        game.physics.arcade.overlap(g.sprite, t.sprite, garbHitTrash);                                                            
    });                                                                                                                           
});
```

I have a garbageList and a trashList and they have a method for overlaping called garbHitTrash.

When garbHitTrash is called it just "throws the garbage on the trash" destroying its sprite and popping it from then garbList.

```
function garbHitTrash(garb, trash) {
    if(garb.trash === trash.type) {                                                                                                   
        result['acertos']++;                                                                                                          
    } else {                                                                                                                          
        result['erros']++;                                                                                                            
    }                                                                                                                                 
    garb.kill();                                                                                                                      
    popGarbage(garb)                                                                                                                  
    console.log('garbList.length ' + garbList.length);                                                                                
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to completely remove your elements, have a look to the `destroy` method rather than `kill`. Calling `kill` is just a shorthand for setting some properties to `false` (like `alive` or `visible`). However, as your object still exist and is still moving (I suppose, due to the collision), those properties are likely to be set or reset by another component.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a little late, but I just had a similar problem.

let's say I wan't to a.kill() in foo

```
game.physics.arcade.collide(a, b, foo);//funky behavior
game.physics.arcade.collide(b, a, foo);//works as intended
```

At the moment, I have no clue why this is. But it seems to work better if you kill or destroy the 'second' item.